# Where is graphic driver installed?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have Ubuntu 16.04 beside Hackingtosh running on a Lenovo laptop T60P with large screen but it support only up to 3GB RAM. So when I got a T61 that can have 4GB, I first installed Ubuntu 16.04, then copied /home, /usr, /opt, and /var from the former to the latter - thinking it will bring all my work to the new one.

But when it boot, it stays in low-graphic mode.

lspci | grep VGA revealed:

- the old laptop as AMD/ATI Mobility FireGL V5250.
- the new one has NVIDIA Quadro NVS 140M.

I believe the driver for this video card is available in the LiveCD, as it got installed correctly in the initial install. But my copying of the /usr, or /opt file system from the older T60 must have overwritten the proper driver.

My question is: where is the driver installed so I can save a copy to prevent it from being overwritten, or at least able to restore it?

thanks for any insight!

Comment: It matters more whether or not you can install a proper Nvidia driver. System Settings > Software Properties > Additional Drivers (tab), select and apply the recommended version, 340.96 or higher (340 is the Linux LTS driver). The installer hopefully will clean up a bit. Reboot.

Comment: thanks for the input. my problem now is I don't get the GUI to go the route as you pointed out. years ago, I remember using Xconfigurator to manually select the correct driver. But Xconfigurator is no longer there. Is there a command to do that from a shell? I have already installed the current driver for the NVIDIA card. But still the same. something else must be at play too.